# PHP Push into array multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to push some data into a multidimensional array, but can't find the correct syntax anywhere.

```
array_push($price, $row["ShopID"], $row["URL"]);
```

This is my code so far, but this does not make the array multidimensional, it just inserts each item as an individual row in the array. How can I fix this, and make the array multidimensional?

Comment: Wrap both values into an array before you push it?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing an array? Then:

```
array_push($price, array($row["ShopID"], $row["URL"]));
```

or maybe:

```
 array_push($price, $row);
```